# How I can integrate two function in the same request

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: 1]

I want to display the most ordered product with its name but I don't know how to integrate the max and count function in the same request

Comment: So product 51 should show up first in the result? Please provide the expected result for this data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how you can do it:

```
select * from products p
join ( 
   select productid , sum(quantity) quantity
   from orders
   group by productid
) t on t.productid = p.productid
order by quantity desc
```